How to Filter and Query Based on a Computed Column in Laravel?
I'm working on a Laravel project where I need to calculate an estimated_value for each record in my SalesLead model by multiplying the probability and value columns. I want to filter records based on this computed column.
I used a global scope to add the computed column like this:
class EstimatedValueScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void
    {
        $builder->addSelect([
            '*',
            \DB::raw('COALESCE(probability, 0) * COALESCE(value, 0) * 0.01 AS estimated_value'),
        ]);
    }
}

And applied it to my model:
class SalesLead extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new EstimatedValueScope);
    }
}

I want to filter records using this computed column, for example:
$salesLeads = SalesLead::where('estimated_value', '>', 1000000)->get();

But I get an SQL error:
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "estimated_value" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t count(*) as aggregate from "sales_leads" where ("estimated...
                                                         ^

Note: I need to use Eloquent's where method to filter by estimated_value, just like with any other column, and avoid using whereRaw or DB:Raw.
Questions:

How can I properly filter and query based on this computed estimated_value column?
Is using a global scope for this purpose the right approach? If not, what would be the best way to handle this?
How can I ensure that the estimated_value column is included in the query and used correctly for filtering?


I believe that we have to use having instead of where for aggregated columns like estimated_value:
$salesLeads = SalesLead::having('estimated_value', '>', 1000000)->get();

